# SSIS Mysql dataflow multiple statement source

Tags: mysql, ssis, dataflow

I am running into problems with SSIS(2012), mysql(odbc) and dataflow when my sql command is more than one statement. In addition I cannot start the statement with a comment either. This is not a problem when using oledb & sql server.

```
SELECT id FROM id_table WHERE type = 'product' INTO @id;
SELECT name FROM products WHERE id = @id;
```

This isn't the most relevant example. It's just to show what I'm doing. But this will not work with Mysql(ODBC) as my source. I get the following:

```
Table has no columns
```

My work around is using a sub query:

```
SELECT name FROM products WHERE id = (SELECT id from id_table WHERE type = 'product');
```

Also the below with a comment comes up with the same error:

```
/* Test comment */
SELECT name FROM products WHERE id = (SELECT id from id_table WHERE type = 'product');
```

Again, sql server(OLEDB), haven't tried ODBC, has no problems with either case.

My first thought is to check the driver and enable the "Multiple statements" flag, which is already checked. Is there a solution to this in the settings of the driver or in SSIS?

EDIT:

Additional examples:

This works with sql server and odbc source for a dataflow:

```
DECLARE @offer AS VARCHAR(8)
SET @offer = 'WDWD' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,1000 + DATEPART(wk,GETDATE())) 
SELECT * FROM source WHERE cd = @offer
```

The rough equivalent with mysql and odbc source for a dataflow does not:

```
SET @offer = CONCAT('WHW410', LPAD(WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()), 2, '0'));
SELECT * FROM source WHERE cd = @offer;
```

I verified both of these are valid sql in SSMS and sqlyog.

Comment: The first block of code is going to choke because you can't return multiple resultsets to a Data Flow (unless I missed that memo). As part of the metadata validation process, it's going to latch onto the first shape it finds.  The comment issue is likely a driver issue more than an SSIS thing.

Comment: The workaround query is a better method anyway.

Comment: @Zane - this is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. For example I have a sql script that sets 25 variables each of which is used in the clause of a LEFT JOIN, so 25 LEFT JOINs. Maybe sub-queries are still the way to go but using the variables is cleaner as far as readability. FYI - I'm working with Magento and their EAV structure. But the question remains why does the first version fail.

Comment: @billinkc I added another example

Comment: There is a direct correlation between the number of times I've shouted "Why the Frack does this not work" and the times I've dealt with mysql. I strongly believe something is getting fouled up in the ODBC connection to mysql *or* in the case of the "table has no columns", the non-SELECT operations are generating metadata and SSIS is **only** going to look at the first set it sees.. Either way, that's *not* a route I'd want to try and debug. You can try encapsulating this logic into stored procedures and maybe the multi statement operations won't bone it. Or, you do the 25 table join.

Comment: @billinkc I actually am using the stored procedure method. I just keep asking myself if I'm missing something every time this comes up. If you want to move your comment to an answer I will give you credit. Just doesn't seem to work with mysql.